# A method can accept different datatype argument

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

Can any one help me on this problem.

```
void method1 ( string A, datatype_1 B, string C) {};
void method2 ( string A, datatype_2 B, string C) {};
```

Above is my sudo code, I have two methods, method 1 and 2, the logic are 99% identical. Method parameters are almost identical, except for datatype_1, and datatype_2. Is there a way that I can only write one method, and the parameter for datatype_1&2 there's a syntax can detect what kind of data type I passed into?

background:
these two methods are OAuth Post method. datatype_1 and 2 which they are 'StringContent' and 'HttpContent'. requests use either one of the Content type.

is there a way :`void method (string A, datatype_1 ? datatype_2 B`, string C) {}; ??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: We need more details - we've no idea how `B` is used. A complete example would be really helpful. But fundamentally the common approach here is to maintain two methods, but have them both delegate to a single private implementation method. As an aside, when posting sample code, it's still helpful to follow normal naming conventions, to avoid distracting readers.

Comment: I think you are looking for a generic method so check this out: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics. If you need to put limitations on the types used then check this out as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Note that a `StringContent` *is* an `HttpContent` - so do you actually need two methods at all? Could you just have a method with the middle parameter being an `HttpContent`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods). If you implement them in your function you can use it like so with type checking to do different things with the different types that are passed:

```
void method<T> ( string A, T B, string C) {
    if(B == typeof(datatype_1){}

    if(B == typeof(datatype_2){}
};

method<datatype_1>(arg1,arg2,arg3);
method<datatype_2>(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

This way you can combine the logic for both methods since there is so much overlap between them. Generics are an important way to reduce the amount of redundant code in your codebase.

Comment: I agree that generics are good - but the approach here is *usually* (not always) an anti-pattern, because you don't find out that a given type is invalid until execution time. I would almost always go with two overloads with the two data types that *can* be used, giving callers the compile-time information about that, and then use a common implementation privately where possible.

Comment: Of course, there are plenty of situations where a single generic method *does* make sense - but when you start dealing with individual type situations in the implementation, that's *usually* a sign that generics aren't really a good fit